# Stop Pandas ExcelWriter() creating extra column

Tags: python, pandas

How to I stop Pandas to_excel() function creating an extra column with the indexes in? If I run the following:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_excel('in.xlsx')
#do some stuff to the dataframe
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('out.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()
```

.. the newly created file (`out.xlsx`) has an additional column which I don't want. I just want the columns identified in `df.columns` outputting without the additional indexes column.

This is a small step in a larger process so i can't just manually delete the column. Also, i don't want to use any other Excel writing packages such as XlsxWriter

Many thanks!

Comment: Do `df.to_excel(writer,index=False)` and you should be good.

Comment: Bemused that someone was bothered to mark the question down? Surely the fact that  5 people have up-marked the chosen answer is testament to the fact that others have had the same issue and have navigated to the solution by this question.

Comment: totally agree with @jcanterbury. SO should identify such "downgrades' and penalize them IMHO.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to set `index` property to `false`, like this:

`df.to_excel(writer, index=False)`

As decribed in pandas documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html